# Poor little TO-252 went in a blaze of glory - can you help ID?

Tags: transistors, identification

This guy is from a dishwasher control panel.  I'm having trouble finding a replacement for the entire control unit (that will ship to Japan, anyway) and I am handy with a soldering iron.

Can you take a stab at what you think it might be?

[image: a wider shot, but a bit blurry]

[image: original cropped]

[image: Replacement Board]

Comment: Show us photos of Q1, Q2, Q4 ... please?

Comment: Looks like it is on the primary side, but can you zoom out a bit?

Comment: We don't have permission to view the image, so don't put it behind a firewall if you want us to help you.

Comment: Reminds me of the time I was waiting at an electronics store. Somebody asked the guy behind the counter for "A black thingy with three connections" as replacement for in his TV.

Comment: Do you know why it performed its own spontaneous disassembly? If the cause isn't fixed a new one will likely do the same thing.

Comment: @Colin it difficult to see, but the back tab might not be properly soldered - maybe this caused the smoke coming out.  I would recommend that he orders two  replacements.

Comment: Maximum information helps us help you. Good photo. Also a wider view to help us  ascertain circuit context will probably help. Quite likely a TRIAC - if so various will work. Q1: Look at it's load - is it faulty?  Q2: Is soldering OK?

Comment: By any chance is there a part nearby shaped like [this](https://i.imgur.com/jnCASCp.png) that may have similar evidence of trauma?

Comment: Ah, it blew due to water leaking from the top.

Comment: The blue cap/varistor next to it got scorched, but it's not bloated.  The heat/smoke rose in its direction.  All of you have been great! Yea, Oldfart, I was working my VW bus stalled on a street and a guy walked up and said, 'what's the prob?'. 'I lost a screw for the points.'  He pulled out a handfull, literally, of screws from his pocket, 'any of these work?'

Comment: Someone tried to help by adding an image, but apparently they are now ruined again.

Comment: My own experience tells me that a blown triac usually means also a blown controlling circuit

Comment: photos seem dead :|

Comment: thanks for the edit assist.  Maybe my hosting company doesn't like VPNs; only a guess.  Was trying google drive but you beat me too it:)

Comment: Well, Akihabara didn't have it so I have to use aliexpress.  Though, word is Japan is blocking shipping using regular POST.  So, I'm going to have dishwasher hands for several weeks, it seems.

Comment: AliExpress is rife with counterfeits. Also, first identify the root cause - the triac didn't blow up by itself. You may replace it only to have it blow instantly. I had a very similar case once, in a different device, and it turned out to be a worn out motor. This being a dishwasher  I'd wager a guess it's the pump. The heater is likely controlled by a relay.

Comment: R102 R104 look like they may be damaged also. | Is RV1 a potentiometer or is the black 'shadow a crater? | If it is cratered it MAY be a MOV.| It's a funny place for a pot. Is the tab of Q2 connected to the left hand pin of Q3 (as it appears ) or is the large copper area divided in two? | Part numbers of Q2 and resistances of the nearby resistors with corresponding numbers may help. || I think the copper  strip twixt Q2 and Q3 IS divided. %102 104 54 plus C 11 may form a gate phase control network with RV1 adjusting it. |

Comment: The more I look the somewhat-stranger the circuit looks. Knowing what connected where would help. A d\drawing of the citcuit in this area may help with values.

Comment: The black shadow is from smoke emanating from the TO-252. The smoke rose in that direction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's made by ST Microelectronics based on Logo.

The package is indeed DPAK (TO-252)

Based on the pinout, it's not a MOSFET (either P or N). All of the ST MOSFETs in DPAK have the gate on pin 1 (lower right in the picture orientation), which makes no sense. The control line of this device is pin 3.

This leaves something like a TRIAC or SCR. The DPAK offerings from ST do have their control line an pin 3, so that looks good.

Beyond that with the markings gone it is hard to tell.

Based on other DPAK parts, the part number is split onto two lines. The first line is the series number, the second line is the rest of the part number.

From your part we can make out very little

```
@@4
????0
```

The exact number of digits vary.

One option that fits that bill are the [T4 series](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/thyristors-scr-and-ac-switches/triacs/standard-and-snubberless-triacs/t410.html) **4A logic level Triacs**. These have part numbers that seem to match. For example this one looks pretty darn close to your image.

[image: Similar Triac Part]
<sup>[Image Source](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32738367171.html)</sup>

Looking closer at your image, we can make out something just before the 4 on the first line which could well be the `T`.

Comment: Top sleuthing Tom!  @PlanB do you have photos of any other similar-looking parts on the board?

Comment: Man, Tom, that's just awesome!  I knew that there were not going to be alot of variables in this form-factor, I just don't know components enough to do the great work you did; Thanks so much!  I can probably pick one up in Akihabara.

Comment: Unfortunately, on the board there are no other packages that size, nor any with the same logo.  However, Tom's guess is probably accurate.  In my feeble search, I didn't see any other '252 with a 4 as the last number.

Comment: Silkscreen says Q3, indicating a transistor. Just FYI.

Comment: @Charlie Frequently but not always. You can't always rely on the refdes label to identify the component type, people use weird choices at times. But when it comes down to it, a triac is basically a weird stacked transistor.

Comment: @Tom: Agreed, just wanting to highlight more clues for the clue pool. It would be nice if everything lined up perfectly, including this. I'm not expecting it, though, just hoping for it.

Comment: Honestly, faced with the same problem, I would just reverse engineer the whole circuit until it was obvious what component whent there. I have done this before. The drive circuit is going to be different for a TRIAC, MOSFET, BJT, what-have-you-widget.

Comment: @Charlie, I get that.  But my troubleshooting days ended in the Army in the 80's.  I can't even color band anymore (╥_╥).  Akihabara didn't have it, the 'service shop' has been unresponsive, so I ordered from Aliexpress and hope the component will make it through the post.  I'll just have to roll the dice that Tom Carpenter was correct; he seems sharp, and the guy in Akihabara couldn't source the type to another mfr, which seems to narrow it down to this item even further.

Comment: @PlanB: Well, you can't break it anymore I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Ganbatte tomoyo. Don't electrocute yourself.

Comment: right. I'll let you all know what happens.  The item seems to trigger the water inlet solenoid, as the thing would run but water was not coming in.  It would also just immediately start running when the button was pushed.  I didn't run it long, just enough to see what seemed to be affected.  Thanks Everyone!

Comment: OK, well the wife didn't want to wait for the shipment of bugs so she ordered a new board and... here it is:

Comment: looks like the board hasn't changed much and Q3 is interchangeable as there is mainly a sensitivity difference between the two types of T4.  I plan on doing a repair on the board anyway, just to see if it works.  and now I'm off to wreak havoc (again) with my Makita!